# Wacom Tablet Intuos BT S stylus not detected

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, tablet, wacom, stylus

The first time, I followed all the steps at https://linuxwacom.github.io/ to install a Wacom CTL 4100 WL (BT S).
Did not work.
After a long time trying to find the problem, instead of using `apt-get`, using `git clone` to install the drivers seems to partially solve the problem.

Now, the tablet configuration menu appears - I can configure the buttons - but the pen menu indicates that it was not detected.
There is no reaction when the pen is on the tablet.

What should I do to repair and function?